# Beautiful Soup 4 Python3: bs4 keeps returning unwanted data in for loop

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my comment soup (a list of comments):

```
<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/serio_blanc" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/49378332_100_3.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/serio_blanc" target="_blank">
     serio_blanc
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       12 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912128729714032" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Lijkt net als een van die apologize video's op YouTube.
   <br/>
   Ze weten goed wat ze gedaan hebben en geven er in werkelijkheid niks om, dit is meer om imago proberen te redden
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry indent-1">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/ralphie85" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_86_100_v0.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/ralphie85" target="_blank">
     ralphie85
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="status">
     <img alt="" class="emoji" draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/13.0.0/72x72/1f1f3-1f1f1.png"/>
    </span>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912279024622021" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="/aid/a0RjwNq" target="_blank">
    @serio_blanc
   </a>
   juist
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/1648" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/37556305_100_3.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/1648" target="_blank">
     1648
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       5 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912650079763115" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   de nederlandse wet stelt dus ook niks meer voor. Het klootjesvolk moet wel aan alle kut regels houden, maar iemand van de elite zegt 3 keer sorry en komt er mee weg. Ik dacht dat communistische landen corrupt waren, maar holy shit. De elite staat boven de wet.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry indent-1">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/rikkie931" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/9940561_100_1.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/rikkie931" target="_blank">
     rikkie931
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       2 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159913157867076249" target="_blank">
       6d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="/aid/aADBzj0" target="_blank">
    @1648
   </a>
   als jij een foto online zet waarin je je niet aan de regels houdt dan krijg je geen boete.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry indent-1">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/bigjoenl" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/40945603_100_2.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/bigjoenl" target="_blank">
     bigjoenl
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159915061170725389" target="_blank">
       6d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="/aid/a75nG2x" target="_blank">
    @rikkie931
   </a>
   waar is de Corona Gestapo als je ze nodig hebt.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry comment-highlight">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/the_tender" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_54_100_v0.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/the_tender" target="_blank">
     the_tender
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       3 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159914257895447420" target="_blank">
       6d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   1) Je bent als minister nogal naiëf als je in zo'n periode een bruiloft organiseert.
   <br/>
   2) Je bent zielig als je als fotograaf in de bosjes gaat liggen bij de bruiloft van een minister om te zien of iedereen zich wel aan alle regeltjes houdt.
   <br/>
   3) je bent hypocriet als je beweert dat een minister zijn werk niet meer zou kunnen doen omdat hij één keer een regel heeft overtreden.
   <br/>
   4) Je bent als minister ongelofelijk dom als je op zo'n moment niet snapt dat, ondanks dat het maar een klein foutje is, je politieke carrière ten einde is en je beter op kunt stappen.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry indent-1">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/bigjoenl" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/40945603_100_2.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/bigjoenl" target="_blank">
     bigjoenl
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       5 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159915104310083614" target="_blank">
       6d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="/aid/aRrwd7" target="_blank">
    @the_tender
   </a>
   een “foutje” waaraan je als burger een strafblad over kunt houden, kun je niet bepaald klein noemen.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry indent-1">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/longpostpot8os" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/51171716_100_17.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/longpostpot8os" target="_blank">
     longpostpot8os
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="status">
     <img alt="" class="emoji" draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/13.0.0/72x72/1f1f3-1f1f1.png"/>
    </span>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       1 point
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159951579916492601" target="_blank">
       2d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   <a href="/aid/aRrwd7" target="_blank">
    @the_tender
   </a>
   eens, behalve dan dat goedbedoelde burgers een strafblad hebben alleen omdat ze een taartje met hun moeder wilden eten. Iets dat ernstige implicaties kan hebben voor jou, aangezien een VOG moeilijk wordt en die wel vaak gevraagd wordt als je wilt gaan werken. Daarnaast heeft hij keihard geroepen dat wie zich er niet aan houdt een aso is. Ja dan is dit wel extra pijnlijk. In eerste instantie was ik ook coulant toen ik het hoorde, maar zag daarna weer oude beelden waarop hij bovengenoemde zei
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/ralphie85" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_86_100_v0.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/ralphie85" target="_blank">
     ralphie85
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="status">
     <img alt="" class="emoji" draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/13.0.0/72x72/1f1f3-1f1f1.png"/>
    </span>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       1 point
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912276445713106" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Ik ga elke dag de fout in en ik beloof niks.
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/123whatyousee" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/19106531_100_2.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/123whatyousee" target="_blank">
     123whatyousee
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159934978635243685" target="_blank">
       4d
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Gepakt op de corona regels en getrouwd, dubbele pech
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/pizzapleece1" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/2113218_100_2.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/pizzapleece1" target="_blank">
     pizzapleece1
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="status">
     <img alt="" class="emoji" draggable="false" src="https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/v/13.0.0/72x72/1f1f2-1f1f3.png"/>
    </span>
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <!-- -->
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912374452745873" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   Afzetten die staatsmongool
  </div>
  <!-- -->
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="comment-entry">
 <div class="avatar">
  <div class="image-container">
   <a href="https://9gag.com/u/tampasta" target="_blank">
    <img loading="lazy" src="https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/56518001_100_3.jpg"/>
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="payload">
  <div class="info">
   <div class="info-container">
    <a class="username" href="https://9gag.com/u/tampasta" target="_blank">
     tampasta
    </a>
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <!-- -->
    <span class="meta">
     <!-- -->
     <span>
      <span class="points">
       8 points
      </span>
      <span>
       ·
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="time">
      <a class="comment-permalink" href="http://9gag.com/gag/aoPx5nm#cs_comment_id=c_159912333004935937" target="_blank">
       3 Sep
      </a>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="media">
   <a class="img-embed" href="https://comment-cdn.9gag.com/image?ref=9gag.com#https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg" target="_blank">
    <picture>
     <source srcset="https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700wp_0.webp" type="image/webp"/>
     <img loading="lazy" src="https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg"/>
    </picture>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
   <span>
    <a class="reply" href="javascript:void(0);">
     Reply
    </a>
   </span>
   <div class="vote-buttons">
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-up">
     </span>
    </a>
    <span class="seperator">
    </span>
    <a class="" href="javascript:void(0);">
     <span class="icn-down">
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <!-- -->
   <!-- -->
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="extra-menu">
  <a class="menu-trigger" href="javascript:void(0);">
   <span class="drop">
   </span>
  </a>
  <!-- -->
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
 </div>
</div>
```

And this is the code I have so far to extract images from a specific place:

```
for comment in comment_soup:
    username = comment.find('a', {'class': 'username'}).text
    
    try:
        image = comment.find('div', {'class': 'media'}).find('img')['src'] #needs to be more specific
    except:
        print('oops, no image')

    print(username)
    print(image)
```

However, the output of bs4 still gives me the same image over and over for every comment, instead of for only the comment that contains that exact image.

Output:

```
oops, no image
serio_blanc
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
ralphie85
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
1648
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
rikkie931
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
bigjoenl
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
the_tender
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
bigjoenl
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
longpostpot8os
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
ralphie85
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
123whatyousee
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
oops, no image
pizzapleece1
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
tampasta
https://img-comment-fun.9cache.com/media/anQXnyq/a6pd2V71_700w_0.jpg
```

The goal is to extract the images contained in the div class=media section of the html, and not the avatar image. For some reason it just returns the image in the media class from the last comment with each loop.
I do not really know what to make of this. I have tried adding more path specifics but that provided the same result. What am I missing here? If I loop over a soup list, does the soup in the loop still scan the entire document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML, there aren't `<div>` with `class="media"`, so the `.find()` returns `None` every time. Change `"media"` to `"image-container"` to obtain desired results (`txt` is your HTML code from the question):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')


for comment in soup.select('.comment-entry'):
    username = comment.find('a', {'class': 'username'}).get_text(strip=True)

    try:
        image = comment.find('div', {'class': 'image-container'}).find('img')['src'] #needs to be more specific
    except:
        print('oops, no image')
        image = '-'

    print(username)
    print(image)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
serio_blanc
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/49378332_100_3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ralphie85
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_86_100_v0.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1648
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/37556305_100_3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rikkie931
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/9940561_100_1.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bigjoenl
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/40945603_100_2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
the_tender
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_54_100_v0.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bigjoenl
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/40945603_100_2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
longpostpot8os
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/51171716_100_17.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ralphie85
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/default-avatar/1_86_100_v0.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123whatyousee
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/19106531_100_2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pizzapleece1
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/2113218_100_2.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tampasta
https://accounts-cdn.9gag.com/media/avatar/56518001_100_3.jpg
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I have edited my question, I'm sorry about the confusion! I don't need the avatar images, I just need the images from the media folder, which, as you have remarked, is absent in most of the comments. However, it is present in the comments that use an image as a reply instead of text (I'm sure you've noticed I'm parsing 9gag here). But thank you for your effort, though. But your code has given me the solution anyways! Thank you! I just added 'image = 'NaN'' to the exception. I upvote your answer.